# How do I retrieve a path from a Spring Cloud Gateway Route in a human-readable format?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

`Route` doesn't provide methods such as `getPath()`. I, however, can get an instance of `AsynchPredicate` type by invoking `getPredicate()` on it. What I do from then on is beyond my understanding at the moment

```java
public String getPath(Route route) {
    // your solution goes here
}
```

How do I retrieve a path from a Spring Cloud Gateway Route in a human-readable format?

I use the term "path" the same way it's used in the `PredicateSpec` class. Notice it's not the same as "uri"

```java
// a static Gateway route which uses predicateSpec.path() may look like this

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator creditServiceRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/api/v1/credit-cards")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/api/v1", "/auth"))
                        .uri(CREDIT_SERVICE_URL))
```

Comment: what about `route.getUri().getPath();` is it what you need ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa `uri` is where a request is forwarded